# How to get substring out of String in this case?

Tags: java, android, string

I have a string that looks like this:

[image]

I only want to get the strings for events and args in two separate strings. Basically I just want what says "statusChanged" in a variable one and "{"newStatus":"disarmed"}" and in second I need this.
How can I do this?

Comment: Please put your code snippet in your question instead of a link to an image, so it will be way easier for people to help you

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! You seem to be under the impression that StackOverflow is a site where you post a problem and get some code in return. This is in fact not the case. Your question will most likely be closed or even deleted shortly. To prevent this from happening in the future, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [take a look at the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). In particular, [make yourself famlilar as to what is regarded as on-topic around here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I ended up solving it like this

```
 String[] eventAux = events[2].split(":");
 String[] argsAux = events[3].split(":");
 String event = eventAux[2].replace("\"", "");
 String arg =  argsAux[3].replace("\"", "").replace("}", "").replace("data", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a regular expression.

You could also try to parse the JSON-String first and then get the Strings from the parsed Object.

Comment: The String in the image is not even a valid JSON.

Comment: The data-part looks like rows from a JSON-String

Answer (score 1):

try this , here **dataString** is your String.

```
    String FirstString,SecondString;
    int FirstIndex,SecondIndex;
    FirstIndex = dataString.indexOf("data: \"event\": ") +15;// 15 characters "data: \"event\": "
    SecondIndex = dataString.indexOf("data: \"args\": ") +14;// 14 characters "data: \"args\": "
    FirstString = dataString.substring(FirstIndex,dataString.indexOf(",",FirstIndex));
    SecondString = dataString.substring(SecondIndex,dataString.indexOf("data:",SecondIndex));
    System.out.println(FirstString);
    System.out.println(SecondString);
```

it helps you to get substring.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into consideration that the provided string is not a valid JSON, you can try this code:

```
List<String> result = Stream.of(s.split("data:"))
            .map(String::trim)
            .filter(l -> l.startsWith("\"event\"") || l.startsWith("\"args\""))
            .map(l -> l.trim().split(":", 2)[1])
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

which will return a list with two elements, in your case.